# Export Powershell Object to CSV - Access Denied

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, export-csv

I'm trying to get the permission of the calendar folder on a set user, then export it to a CSV, so we can easily view the permissions.

When I run this command:

```cs
Get-Mailbox |
    Get-MailboxPermission |
    Select-Object AccessRights, User, Identity, IsValid |
    Export-Csv -Path 'c:\Users\Connor\Desktop'
```

I get this error:

```
Export-Csv : Access to the path 'C:\Users\Connor\Desktop' is denied.
At line:1 char:89
+ ... hts,User,Identity,IsValid | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\Users\Connor\Desktop'
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Export-Csv], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

Comment: You forgot to ask your question.

Comment: You also forgot to add a filename for the csv file after the path to your desktop..

Comment: add a filename: `Export-Csv -Path 'c:\Users\Connor\Desktop\PermRep.csv'`, also make sure you have write permissions to the target folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the PowerShell has write permission to the folder you're trying to write to.  You can do this by

1. Relaunching Powershell as Administrator
2. Specifying a folder that PS can write to *without* elevated permissions

   - Try `C:\temp\` (plus your `filename.csv`)
   - Or call [`Path.GetTempPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath) in PS with `[System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()`

**See Also**: [Export-Csv - Access to the path 'C:\export.csv' is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60611518/1366033)