# PowerShell export-csv to network drive

Tags: powershell, export-csv

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object name | Export-Csv -Path \\some\network\location
```

Returns error:

```
Export-Csv : Access to the path '\\some\network\location' is denied.
```

On folder security settings I have full access.

Comment: Message sounds clear. Aren't you running your script as another user ?

Comment: No just as myself.

Comment: To access a network share, you have to pass two borders: Share permissions and NTFS permissions. You just checked the NTFS permissions. Do you have write permissions for the network share? (Look for the tab "share")

Comment: Run as admin (based on looking at other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60611518/export-csv-access-to-the-path-c-export-csv-is-denied)

Comment: `\some\network\location` is not a (absolute) network path format (it even questions the current [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers). Anyways, this should be something `\\Server\Share\My.csv`, `\\Domain\Share\My.csv` or `H:\Share\My.csv` (assuming that `H:` is redirected to a network share). If it is intended to be a relative path, the question is: *what is the current location*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uggg... I didn't define the file name in the path. This works:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object name | Export-Csv -Path \\some\network\location\ADUsers.csv
```

Comment: Just noticing you don't need `-Properties *` if your just going to select the Name property. That comes back as default, so you can remove `-Properties *` altogether.